# MyGet and Cake, generate version number

Tags: c#, cakebuild, myget

I'm using a custom cake build script w/ MyGet. I had previously used a line like so on AppVeyor

`var version = AppVeyor.IsRunningOnAppVeyor ? AppVeyor.Environment.Build.Version : "0.0.1";`

to get a version number from the build CI platform. However on MyGet I have a MyGet.IsRunningOnMyGet but I don't seem to have a build version number or environment object in MyGet . Any suggestions on how I should be getting the build number so I can pass it to the 'pack' command further down in the cake script?

Comment: did you get it sorted, was answer below helpful? Or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like the [IMyGetProvider](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.MyGet/IMyGetProvider/) supports that yet, that said it's available as an environment variable
[image: MyGet version environment]

So you should be able to do

```
var version = EnvironmentVariable("PackageVersion");
```

See MyGet documentation for [Available environment Variables](https://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/build-services#Available_Environment_Variables).